# Child tables sum alias error

Tags: mysql, mariadb

A parent table: **Loads** and 2 child tables: **Invoices** & **Payments**.
All linked on Load_id.
Getting the sum of all invoices and Payments for each load.

This gives me the error: [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'I.Load_Id' in 'on clause'

```
SELECT L.Load_Id,
I.Invoice_Total,
P.Payment_Total
FROM Loads AS L

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT 
SUM(Invoice_Total) AS Invoice_Total
FROM invoices
GROUP BY Load_Id
) AS I
ON I.Load_Id = L.Load_Id

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT 
SUM(Amount) AS Payment_Total
FROM Payments
GROUP BY Load_Id
) AS P
ON P.Load_Id = L.Load_Id
```

This also gives me the error: [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'I.Load_Id' in 'on clause'

```
SELECT Loads.Load_Id,
I.Invoice_Total,
P.Payment_Total
FROM Loads 

LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT 
SUM(Invoice_Total) AS Invoice_Total
FROM invoices
GROUP BY Load_Id
) AS I
ON I.Load_Id = Loads.Load_Id

LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT 
SUM(Amount) AS Payment_Total
FROM Payments
GROUP BY Load_Id
) AS P
ON P.Load_Id = Loads.Load_Id
```

I have tried many variations, but clearly I'm not getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not selecting in your subqueries any field called `Load_Id`, and mySQL is complaining about that. You did already group by it, so all that is needed is to select it like in the query below so you can join on it.

```
SELECT L.Load_Id,
I.Invoice_Total,
P.Payment_Total
FROM Loads AS L

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT 
SUM(Invoice_Total) AS Invoice_Total, Load_Id
FROM invoices
GROUP BY Load_Id
) AS I
ON I.Load_Id = L.Load_Id

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT 
SUM(Amount) AS Payment_Total, Load_Id
FROM Payments
GROUP BY Load_Id
) AS P
ON P.Load_Id = L.Load_Id
```

Comment: How do I save that select as a view? When I try, I get - 1039 - View's Select contains a subquery in the From clause

Comment: @AlphaBase: Seems there is a [workaround](http://blog.gruffdavies.com/2015/01/25/a-neat-mysql-hack-to-create-a-view-with-subquery-in-the-from-clause/). Quote from the article linked: "The trick is to refactor the subquery into a view of its own, which you can then join to in the VIEW you want!"